# Blender eats up +8gb of storage on my C Drive when on material preview

Tags: rendering, materials

I've got a blender project where I'm using a bunch of textures, and whenever I go to material preview or render preview I start losing a lot of storage on my C Drive. This is making the project difficult to work on since I don't have much space on my C Drive.

I used space sniffer to find out what exactly was eating at my storage and it looks like it's the pagefile.sys file. I'm not sure why my project is eating up so much space. My textures folder is only around 2gb and I'm not trying to render anything. I've checked online, but couldn't find anything on it.

Is there a setting in blender I can change to reduce the amount of storage it takes?

Comment: The Question Is Similar and has a possible Answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112359/blender-eats-space-on-c-drive

Comment: Has your computer a dedicated graphic card or an onboard/integrated GPU? While graphic cards have their on memory (VRAM) the onboard GPUs share the memory (RAM) with the CPU. The pagefile.sys is Window's swap file. It's used when programs require more memory than the PC has RAM. Then Windows begins to write the RAM content to the swap file. Check the RAM usage in the task manager. You can't tell from the size of the textures on disk how much memory you need, because the files are compressed while the data in memory is uncompressed.

Comment: If you can't get more disk space & can't upgrade your PC's RAM or get a better graphic card then you need to reduce the texture size. Keep in mind that 2k textures require 4x more space as 1k textures because length and width are doubled. Use low-res textures for objects that is in the background or far away from camera. That's basically what game engines do to improve performance.

Comment: I believe my laptop has an integrated GPU, but I'm not sure. The project is taking up all of my RAM though.
I've replaced some meshes with a seamless texture instead of a baked set, and that's reduced the amount of storage it takes. I'll probably do some more texture optimization to reduce this more.

Now that I know what's causing this issue, I can plan around it for future scenes.
Thanks for the help.